# Prevent access to crashlytics and app-distribution by another app with same package name and google-services.json is created

Tags: android, firebase, security, google-cloud-platform

Since google-services.json is reachable and api-key is accessible to other developers, it becomes kind of vulnerability. When I restrict my app's api-key in Google Cloud console for Android apps with my app's package name and fingerprint(including all 37 apis for restriction) I can still use same api-key in another Android app.

To try it, I created a sample app with the same package name of my original app, used same google-services.json and I saw I can use crashlytics and app-distribution with my original app's Firebase account.

I also tried app-check feature of play integrity but couldn't manage to restrict it.

How should I prevent my google-services.json to be used in another app?

Comment: It's not a security problem to expose your API key.  Firebase can't function at all without it, and once it hits the client app in any way, it's essentially public information. If you're concerned about security, you should instead make sure your security rules are correct (for those products that use them), and use Firebase App Check.

Comment: I also tried Firebase App Check but it didn't help. Maybe I am doing something wrong or deficient. The question is how can we prevent accessing our app's Firebase features like crashlytics and app-distribution if another app with same package name and google-services.json is created? Because once he/she gets package name and google services public info, someone can do it for hack reasons and publish its app in our Firebase cloud.

Comment: If you have concerns about this, you should contact [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) directly.  You simply can't use Firebase without an API key in the client app, you can't stop someone from getting that API key once it's part of a published app, and it's never been considered a security problem to have these keys in the apps.